# Find where array of objects does not contain objects with param with specific value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using Mongoose and have a schema like this:

```
var User = new mongoose.Schema({
    registrations:[{
        fieldA: String,
        fieldB: String,
    }]
});

var UserModel = mongoose.model('User', User);
```

I want to find all users that their registrations array does not contain objects with `fieldA == 'specific value'`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`$ne`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/ne/#op._S_ne) operator and dot notation to do this:

```
UserModel.find({'registrations.fieldA': {$ne: 'specific value'}}, cb);
```

When used with an array field like this, `$ne` will only match docs where no array element contains the specific value.